Synchronize expo-av Video playback with Visualization using Skia Canvas
I'm currently facing the issue of synchronizing a visualization (which I'm drawing on a Skia Canvas) with a video (using expo-av). The basic idea is that I'm highlighting parts of the video using a rectangle, circles, lines, etc. that I'm drawing on the canvas. However the issue I'm facing is that the video and the visualization are often out of sync, with the visualization lagging behind a few frames or milliseconds behind the video, so it appears to be a performance issue. Most likely this is cause by a not so optimal drawing approach from my side. I use the onPlaybackStatusUpdate method to update a sharedValue holding the milliseconds and then use a useDerivedValue to get the data for the frame and then adding the individual components such as circles, lines, etc. to the canvas. Below is an example showing my current approach. My most pressing questions are:

Why is the forceUpdate call necessary? Updating only the sharedValue has no effect.
Is this a good approach? Is there a faster or more efficient way to draw lots of primitives on a screen?
Is it maybe possible to draw directly on a Canvas (something like a paint() method) that might be more performant?

import { Canvas, Circle, Line } from "@shopify/react-native-skia";
import { ResizeMode, Video } from "expo-av";
import { useMemo, useReducer, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Dimensions, View } from "react-native";
import { useDerivedValue, useSharedValue } from "react-native-reanimated";

export default function App() {
  // video info
  const videoRef = useRef<Video>(null);
  const videoWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
  const [videoDuration, setVideoDuration] = useState(27000);
  const [videoHeight, setVideoHeight] = useState((16 / 9) * videoWidth);
  const [, forceUpdate] = useReducer((x) => x + 1, 0);

  // prepare data for frames
  const dataForFrames = useMemo(() => {
    const numberOfFrames = (videoDuration / 1000.0) * 100;

    const data = [];
    for (let frame = 0; frame < numberOfFrames; frame++) {
      const progress = frame / numberOfFrames;

      const circles = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        circles.push({ x: videoWidth * progress, y: 20 + i * 8 });
      }

      data.push({ frame, circles });
    }

    return data;
  }, [videoDuration, videoWidth]);

  // shared value to get current milliseconds of video
  const milliseconds = useSharedValue(0);

  // derived value to get data for frame
  const circles = useDerivedValue(() => {
    const video = videoRef.current;
    if (!video) {
      return [];
    }

    const frame = (milliseconds.value / 1000.0) * 100;
    return dataForFrames.reduce((prev, curr) =>
      Math.abs(frame - curr.frame) < Math.abs(frame - prev.frame) ? curr : prev
    ).circles;
  });

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
      }}
    >
      <Video
        ref={videoRef}
        style={{
          width: videoWidth,
          height: videoHeight,
        }}
        source={{
          uri: "https://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4",
        }}
        onLoad={(status) => {
          if (status.isLoaded && status.durationMillis) {
            setVideoDuration(status.durationMillis);
          }
        }}
        onReadyForDisplay={(e) => {
          setVideoHeight(
            (e.naturalSize.height / e.naturalSize.width) *
              Dimensions.get("window").width
          );
        }}
        useNativeControls
        resizeMode={ResizeMode.CONTAIN}
        isLooping
        onPlaybackStatusUpdate={(status) => {
          if (status.isLoaded) {
            milliseconds.value = status.positionMillis;
            // why is this necessary?
            forceUpdate();
          }
        }}
        shouldPlay={true}
        progressUpdateIntervalMillis={5}
      />
      <Canvas
        pointerEvents="none"
        style={{
          width: videoWidth,
          height: videoHeight,
          marginTop: -videoHeight,
        }}
      >
        {circles.value.map((c, i) => (
          <Circle r={4} cx={c.x} cy={c.y} key={i} />
        ))}

        {circles.value.map((c, i) => (
          <Line
            p1={{ x: c.x, y: c.y }}
            p2={{ x: c.x - 20, y: c.y }}
            strokeWidth={3}
            key={i}
          />
        ))}
      </Canvas>
    </View>
  );
}

The used packages in my package.json are:
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "~3.2.1",
    "@shopify/react-native-skia": "1.2.3",
    "expo": "~51.0.8",
    "expo-av": "~14.0.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },

